# How to configure Postfix SMTP to mail to another server from external client?

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot

I have a server with Dovecot and Postfix installed. I have set up squirrelmail which works. I want to be able to send mail from a mail client on a computer other than the server (external) to gmail/hotmail ect. I get permission denied, and the logs say samothing with Relay SMTP issue..

What configuration is neccesary to do this?

For example, how can it be that I can send mail from the mail server with my domain example.com to gmail if I do it from squirrelmail, but not if I use example.com with an external mail client??

UPDATE:

I added this to main.cf:

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/controlled_envelope_senders
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch permit_sasl_authenthenticated

Now I get "Temporary lookup failure" when sending from external client
I though it had to do with smtpd_sender_login_maps so I commented it out, but then I get "sender adress rejected: not owned by user .."

Comment: Enable authenticated SMTP

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Either :

- add the ip-address (range) of that computer to a list of trusted ip-addresses (typically the [`mynetworks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks) setting)
- or first configure the Postfix server to support [SMTP authentication](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) and then set the mail client on the computer to authenticate with a username and password.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your links and updated, but still problem